# How to create labels and subplot for a trajectory graph using matplot in R?

Tags: r, matplotlib

I am trying to duplicate the image below that was created using the matplotlib from python with R. I do not know how to add code for the x-, y-, and z-lim as well as the x-, y-, and z-lab and was hoping someone could help me? Also, is there a way to put a subplot in the middle of the main graph that zooms in on a narrow limit range of the trajectory graph?

My code so far is:

```
matplot(out, type = "p")
```

My old Python graph

[image]

The new R graph, in development:

[image]

Update after @eipi10 helped.

```
        #Main Plot with labels and axis limits
matplot(out, main="", type = "l",
        xlab = "x label", ylab = "y label",
        xlim = c(0, 100), ylim = c(-100, 500),
        lwd = c(1,1,2))

#Add legend
legend(0, -50, c("x", "y1", "y2"),
       lty = c(1,2,3), lwd = 2,
       col = c("black", "red", "green"))

#Add subplot
subplot(matplot(out, type = "l",
       xlab = "", ylab="", lwd = c(1,1,2),
       xlim = c(50,70), ylim = c(-10,10),
       cex.axis = 0.8, las = 1), 
       125, 110, size = c(2, 1))
```

Comment: I think the issue is that your main plot has `xlim=c(0,100)`, but you placed the subplot at x=125, which is outside the plot coordinates.

Comment: It stopped the size error, but now says, "Error in plot.window(...) : 
  graphical parameter "las" has the wrong length".

Comment: `las` should be a single digit (0, 1, 2 or 3) (run `?par` for details about `las` and other graphical parameters). Did it somehow get changed while you were editing the code?

Comment: No, it is still there. I had tried the other parameters too. I was looking to see if I could somehow move the subplot in the middle while removing the default legend at the top right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example with fake data:

```
library(Hmisc)  # For subplot function

# Fake parameters (for adding to plot title)
a = 0.158
b = 0.004
g1 = 1.5 

# Fake data
x = seq(0,100,0.1)
y1 = x/2*cos(x)
y2 = x^2/100

# Main plot with labels and axis limits
matplot(as.matrix(data.frame(x,y1,y2)), type="l", 
        xlab="x label", ylab="y label",
        xlim=c(0,1000), ylim=c(-100,150),
        lwd=c(1,1,2), las=1)

# Add title
title(substitute(paste("Parameters: ", lambda[1], "=", g1), list(g1=g1)), line=3.2)
title(substitute(paste(alpha, "=", a,", ", beta, "=", b), list(a=a, b=b)), line=2)
title(paste0("Or without math symbols: alpha = ", a, ", beta = ", b),
      line=0.65, font.main=1)

# Add legend
legend(0, -50, c("x","y1","y2"),
       lty=c(1,2,3), lwd=2,
       col=c("black","red","green"))

# Add subplot
subplot(matplot(as.matrix(data.frame(x,y1,y2)), type="l", 
                xlab="", ylab="", lwd=c(1,1,2),
                xlim=c(50,70), ylim=c(-10,10),
                cex.axis=0.8, las=1),
        125, 110, size=c(2, 1.75))
```

[image]

Comment: You not only answered my question, but you also answered other questions I have been working on. I extremely appreciate your answer, it has already helped.

However, I am curious if you know how I can remove the generic default "x" on the title if I do not want a title? The post-doc I am working with has asked me to make the graphs without a title (When publishing some journals do not like Titles on the graph itself, but above or below it). Whenever I create the graph without a title (i.e., I have used title(), main(), and legend().) it shows an "x" for the title.

Comment: Sorry, accidentally deleted the comment you just responded to. My comment was, just add `main=""` to the call to `matplot` to get an empty title.

Comment: Update your question with the code you're running and I'll see if I can help.